# Opening OpenOffice documents in Microsoft Office

Tags: microsoft-office, plugins, openoffice, documents, format

Are there any good extensions out there for MS office to Open up open office files? The problem is here at our company some people use Microsoft Office and others use OpenOffice

Comment: LibreOffice is able to write the legacy (e.g. `.doc`) formats and also the new ones (`.docx`). Dunno how well, but I'd try that first. Besides, I've occasionally sent out `.odt` files to Microsoft only coworkers and got no complaints... it seems MS *does* handle the standard formats after all ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a "Sun ODF Plugin" - which in the days before Oracle was freely available, if I'm remembering right. Anyway, here's the link: http://www.sun.com/software/star/odf_plugin/index.jsp

And question #7 in the FAQ details the differences between this one and the odf-converter at sourceforge: http://www.sun.com/software/star/odf_plugin/faqs.jsp

Hope, this helps,
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

http://odf-converter.sourceforge.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice can save documents in MS office format. Some features may not work properly, but basically things should work. Just be sure that you always have your local version in OO format.